# BAM Archive database - Reduce size

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-bam

Is there a way to reduce BAM Archive database size? We are currently moving the data from BAM Primary DB to BAM Archive. But now BAM Archive DB contains large amount of data which takes huge space. I tried using Biztalk Terminator for this but DB is not getting connected on BT

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't really related to ANSI/ISO SQL...)

Comment: @jarlh BizTalk databases will always be Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: One of the things to check is to see if you have a lot of tables ending with _Failed in your BAM Archive.  If you do, you can drop these tables.  Other than that you may have to alter how long to retain data in the BAM archive,  I'll see if I can dig those commands up.   This  is not really a programming question, more a server maintenance question.